# When search bar is tapped, bar button items are dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a navigation bar with a `search bar` and two `UIBarButtonItems`.  Here how it looks like:

[image]

The problem is, when I tap the `search bar`, the two `UIBarButtonItems`are dismissed, so I can't access them. To do that, I should tap "cancel", which dismisses all searched items and returns the initial state of the `table view`. Here how my navigation bar looks like, when I tap the `search bar`:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share some code ? And did you check if the bar button items are dismissed or hidden ?

Comment: @Gihan, you need the code for configuring `search bar` or what? Isn't this the default behaviour of the `search bar`? I'm saying that, because I haven't explicitly changed its behaviour.

Comment: Don't move your searchBar to navigation bar.

Comment: try vc.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

Comment: @Gihan, yes it works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the navigation controller with a search bar, just implement a search bar on its own. You can have it display when a button is pressed or you can have it statically located on the page.

```
// be sure to add the UISearchBarDelegate to the vc 

var searchController:UISearchController!

func showSearchBar() {
    // initialize and present search bar
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I' ve tried to add it as a `table view`'s header view, but it still behaves in the same old way

Comment: Do you have a git repository for this?

Comment: I've forgotten to set `searchBar`'s `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to false. When it is set, I get the result I want, so there is no need to create a separate one. Anyway, your answer helped me to find the solution, so I'll check it. Thanks